# Unable to delete multiple files via s3cmd (Ceph)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ceph, radosgw

When attempting to delete multiple files in a Ceph bucket, via the s3cmd cli the following error is presented:

```
s3cmd rm --recursive --force s3://search-backup/
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (AccessDenied)
```

Deleting single files with the following works as expected:

```
s3cmd rm s3://search-backup/tests-12-4O9i-QSKbAnNQARHCnA/data-gXYONdsDQ1-87v5vOqsL2g.dat
delete: 's3://search-backup/tests-12-4O9i-QSKbAnNQARHCnA/data-gXYONdsDQ1-87v5vOqsL2g.dat'
```

The bucket has the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam:::user/search_backup"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectRetention",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:RestoreObject",
                "s3:PutBucketObjectLockConfiguration"
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::search-backup/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam:::user/search_backup"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification",
                "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:PutBucketTagging",
                "s3:PutBucketCORS",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::search-backup"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Using `del` instead of `rm` results in the same behavior.

Is there a permission or setting that is being missed?

Comment: You need at least `s3:ListBucket` on the bucket itself, not just objects within the bucket.

Comment: Do you have files that have been multipart uploaded?

Comment: No, they should just be single file uploaded. Is a different permission needed for multipart uploaded files?

Comment: For multipart, you'll also need `GetObjectAttributes` on the objects (your first statement) - can you add that and see if it fixes the issue? Other than that, everything else seems to be granted pretty much 